What's Ender Dragon size in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?
I am currently making an Addon and would like to know the dimensions of the Ender Dragon. On the Minecraft Wiki it says it's 16 blocks long, 16 wide and 8 tall, I think this is at its highest and lowest points of its animation, so what is its dimensions in its actual model that might be found in one of Minecraft's Folders. This may also be done maybe in Java, or if possible in Bedrock, to summon it with no AI and measure it.
I have looked on Sketchfab extensively but when I try to import it doesn't work, so I spent ages finding out how to import it and when I did it was very blocky with the .vox, or, with the .obj, not compatible with Bedrock Entities in Blockbench. I have to finish this model soon.

I need to have finish this by the 13th of June so someone please answer quickly, in the meantime I will continue development

Note that Minecraft Wiki has migrated off Fandom: it's now at https://minecraft.wiki

not really its still there
